# node red array / how to "use" specific place

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

in node red i collect values with "Collector" the collector sends me an "Object" with all pairs of values when one of them is updated:

```
{ "mqtt/1/": "-127.00", "mqtt/0/": "41.94" }
```

with "json" and after with "stringsplit" i got an array of f.e. 9 values:
array [9] (**can be up to 80 pairs of values**)!

```
[ "{", "mqtt/1/", ":", "-127.00", ",", "mqtt/0/", ":", "41.61", "}" ]
```

now i want to have a function node which compares the Value (-127.00) from the Topic (mqtt/1/) with the Value (41.61) from the Topic (mqtt/0/).
this i working ...BUT only if i know which is the first topic/value and which is the second...

```
var outputMsgs = msg.payload;
var top1=outputMsgs[1];
var val1=outputMsgs[3];
var top2=outputMsgs[5];
var val2=outputMsgs[7];
msg = {payload: val1}
var msg2 = {payload: val2}
if (val1>val2)
{var msgOUT={payload: "BIGGER"};}
return [msg, msg2, msgOUT];
```

But the Problem is, that sometimes "mqtt/1/" comes first, sometimes "mqtt/0/" and values will be switched. So now, maybe somebody can help to write a function to pick the right value with the right topic to compare them in the next step.

Maybe is there a Way to look if the topic contains 0, 1 ...80, and then save it in this order in a array???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no way this is Java.  Java doesn't use `var`.  JavaScript does, but even then I'm not 100% clear on what it is you're asking.

Comment: Would checking using `.indexOf("mqtt/1/")` or `.indexOf("mqtt/0/")` work?

Comment: yes it does work with   `.indexOf("mqtt/1/")` ! Is it a way to just to look not at the WHOLE topic like ""mqtt/1/"" but just at ONE number/ONE word in the topic like "1" or like "mqtt"???

Comment: Then do `.split("/")` and the 0th element is the word and the 1st the number.

Comment: so it would be an Array in Array?

Comment: it does work...BUT i have to know on which place ist the topic, so i can split it... CAN I delete all values like (;), (:) etc.. from this array so i ONLY have Topics and Values in `array[i+2]` ` "{", "mqtt/0/MQTT/0/20/1/0/0", ":", "-127.00", ",", "mqtt/0/MQTT/0/58/1/0/0", ":", "41.17", "}"`

Answer (score 1):

If the initial `msg.payload` is truly a javascript object as you describe, ie:

```
msg.payload = { "mqtt/1/": "-127.00", "mqtt/0/": "41.94" }
```

then you can reference the two values as:

```
var value1 = msg.payload["mqtt/1/"];
var value1 = msg.payload["mqtt/2/"];
```

If `msg.payload` is actual a JSON string, then pass the message through a JSON node first to convert it to the object.

There is no need to try splitting the string yourself and parsing the content.

Comment: thank you. as far as i know a node can compare values only if they are GLOBAL or if 2 values are coming into the node in "same time". Because of that I have 2 values incl. topics comming in a "COLLECTOR" node, both values are going to be send  as OBJECT-> next node is a FUNCTION with `var arr = [];
for (var k in msg.payload) {arr.push([k]); arr.push(msg.payload[k]);} 
var msg={payload: arr}
return msg;` so i receive an array and then i habe to parse it with `parse.Float (msg.payload[1]` etc..BUT IT IS NOT ELLEGANT :-( So what is the better way to handle OBJECTs and get values from them?

Comment: or better... what is the better way to compare values, which are NOT comming in the same time and have to be stored/buffered in the node until the next/2nd value comes?